# How would one go about getting an exemption from the gathering limit of the PAUSE Executive Order?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, executive

Say a person wants to get Married in Upstate New York within the most recent revision of the [PAUSE act](https://www.governor.ny.gov/news/no-20224-continuing-temporary-suspension-and-modification-laws-relating-disaster-emergency).  Right now, gatherings are restricted to 10 people. This would cause the wedding to be slimmed down to the limit, which is 10 people.  What feasible legal actions could either spouse do to get an exception on this part of the exective order?

Comment: None, hopefully - a large wedding isn't an essential activity requiring an exemption, so there shouldn't be any legal avenue (short of having the order declared illegal) to get one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no feasible legal actions that you can take. The implausible action is to sue the state on some constitutional grounds and have the order overturned in part. The order contains no appeals process, so you would have to attack the order itself. There are, here and there, lawsuits on Free Expression Clause grounds regarding the shuttering of churches, which stand the greatest chance of prevailing at the level of SCOTUS. Even if the court were to rule that under these circumstances the right to attend mass church meetings cannot be restricted, it is significantly less likely that application of the emergency powers acts to weddings would be found to violate a fundamental right.